# what is the max length of azure storage partition key

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have copied a azure storage table to Azure SQL. I want to create index for PartitionKey. What is the max length of a Azure storage partition key ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it's stated at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179338.aspx: "The partition key may be a string value up to 1 KB in size".

Comment: As UTF-16 is used for strings, I expected that saving strings of length > 512 characters fails, but it does not. Only strings > 1024 characters fail. (Tested using C# API).